# Can I use junction.exe to make a link from a folder that already exists, to another folder?

Tags: windows-8, junction

Every time I tried using junction on an existing folder, I was given an error message that the folder already exist. Is there some sort of special command that can handle this?

Example for clarity: `junction.exe c:\users\Goran\AppData d:\Data\AppData` gives me a message: `"c:\users\Goran\AppData" already exists`. (Duh, I know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target folder must be **empty**.

The operation would succeed if and only if `C:\Users\Goran\AppData` is empty.

The [example of `junction.exe` usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) confirms that. Yet it does not say the target folder, I mean the folder that will become junction, must be empty.

---

[Reparse Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the same as junction points):

> The following restrictions apply to reparse points:
>
> - Reparse points can be established for a directory, but **the directory must be empty**. Otherwise, the NTFS file system fails to establish the reparse point.

Comment: Oh well.. Do you know of any other tool that could do the same thing that junction.exe does? I can't make the AppData folder empty because some files are ALWAYS being used by the OS..

Comment: No other tool can do this because it is *the limitation of the NTFS*.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic You can workaround it by creating another temporary account. Then as administrator move registry files `ntuser.*` from `C:\Users\Goran\AppData` to `D:\Data\AppData`, then remove everything from `C:\Users\Goran\AppData` and create the junction. (Do a backup of registry files just in case something goes wrong.)